# An AngularJS directive is not being rendered in the DOM hierarchy in which it is declared

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which I'm rendering some `<tr>` tags and within my own custom directive.

For some reason the `<tr>` tags are rendering outside of the hierarchy in which they are declared.

In this image you can see that the nodes are rendered outside of the table.

[image: Shows DOM node being rendered outside of where it is declared]

If you take a look at this Plunk in the file rule-list.html, you'll see there's a comment on where I expect the tag should be rendering but it isn't.

http://goo.gl/9STCKP

Sorry for linking to a plunk but it's not a code fragment which I can post which shows the problem. I don't know where the problem is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html structure is invalid

You are using the custom tag `<nc-rule>` as a child of `<tbody>` and then inserting a `<tr>` into that custom tag.

Table elements are very specific about what parent tags they can be inserted in.

When browser can't resolve them as valid it moves them out of the flow.

Instead of using custom tag you should be able to use appropriate table tag with an attribute for directive

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how I can word the question better?